# How do I utilize the dynamic input field function in the manipulate function? Can I use this functionality to import a .xls from an URL dynamically?

Tags: dynamic, import, inputfield

Im trying to get my program to import a .xls for manipulation, I need to import the .xls at an url location dynamically, I did have this at the beginning of my code:

```
url = "http://www.doc.gold.ac.uk//~ma302jh//RegressionExample.xls"

t = Import[url];
```

I got my code working from the same URL location all the time, but now I want to put the dynamic input field in the manipulate function in order to upload any table I wish at any time, I have tried variations of this example below

```
Manipulate[

 If[url =!= "", WolframAlpha[url], "Enter URL"], {{url, ""}, 

  InputField[Dynamic[url], String] &}, t = import[url],
```

But im having a lot of trouble understanding the documentation and syntax regarding both manipulate and how I can import a table within manipulate.

My overal aim is to have an url input field in my code, the program will then map the table data plot points

Answer (score 1):

Does this answer you first concern?

```
 Manipulate[
  t = Quiet[ Check[Import[url], {{"error, please provide a valid link"}}]];

  Pane[TableForm[t], {Full, 300}, Scrollbars -> True,  AppearanceElements -> None]
  ,
  {{url, ""}, InputField[#, String, ImageSize -> {500, 35}] &},
  {t, None}
 ]
```

[image]

You can achieve this in many ways, the question is what is the final goal, for more complex UI please consider writting everything in terms of `DynamicModule`+`Dynamic` instead of `Manipulate`.

Comment: I get the error :Manipulate argument t=Quiet[Check[Import[url],{{error, please provide a valid link}}]];{{url,},http://www.doc.gold.ac.uk//~ma302jh//RegressionExample.xls&} does not have the correct form for a variable specification. >>

Comment: How could I rewrite this in terms of dynamic module or would their be too much to do? also the final goal is to be able to put the url of any table in and have the program use it smoothly.

Comment: I get errors but that's because i'm trying to mix it with all the other stuff, on its own it does work, but with the stuff that I actually need in manipulate, wierd errors

Comment: Okay I understand you, wait a mo

Comment: Okay by saying table data I actually meant utilise the data from a .xls, I jsut want ed an input field so that the url containing the data to import waasnt hardcoded

Comment: @JethroDevøn I'm sorry, but there is an input field there, isnt it? on the top, next to "url" label?

Comment: yeah just not a beautiful one inlaid into the sketch

Comment: @JethroDevøn what sketch? I still don't know if I answered you question...

Comment: The cdf sorry, by sketch I meant .CDF, im a student and they got us writing code in processing im getting myself badly mixed up with languages, my communication skills have actually gone down hill since starting to code, this project isnt coureswork of anykind but to see it through would be a weight off my mind.

Comment: @JethroDevøn No need to panic. Just focus, say what needs to be done. And it probably can be, I just need to understand it.

Comment: Okay I need their to be a box inlaid within my program, I have a cdf that displays plot points smartly, I want to put URLs in their so I can have the program automaticly import the .xls and the urls location and have my program utilize it, my program displays the plot points.

Comment: are you still there?

Comment: @JethroDevøn can you join [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21407/room-for-minthao-2011-and-kuba)?

Comment: @JethroDevøn it seems youhave not been there.